# What to do when a NPC blocks a doorway or exit?

Tags: fallout-2

In Fallout 2, there are children everywhere.  I found myself stuck in the sheriff's office in Redding because a child blocked the way and would not let me pass.  I tried the following:

1. resting for a few days to see if the kid would move (didn't work)
2. talking to Sulik and asking him to change his distance from me (didn't work)
3. giving the kid a nuke soda (didn't work)
4. giving the kid a fruit (didn't work)

I finally kicked the kid and the whole town came after me, including the sheriff.  I do not have enough XP to exit the town in one piece.  I've done a few side quests on this game and would hate to lose that and redo it.

Is there any way to get a NPC to move if they are blocking an exit or doorway?

Comment: Props for finally just giving the little bastard the boot! Note that killing a child will earn you the Childkiller perk: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Childkiller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to many sources, there's a shove command that you can use to move npc out of the way.

[Gamefaq 1](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/63576-fallout-2/48393136)

> What you are saying was a major complaint about the original Fallout, but Fallout 2 fixed it by added a "shove command." Right click on the person you want to shove out of your way, and one of the boxes should shove them.
>
> Well yeah. But you have to right-click until you get the arrow cursor first.

[Gamefaq 2](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/63576-fallout-2/answers/101444-how-do-you-push-people-out-of-the-way)

> Right click till you get your pointer. Then on the character you want to move, right click and hold till the drop list appears. Then look for a hand and arrow in the same box, move your mouse down untill this is highlighted. Then release the right mouse button. The character will move in a direction from your characters line of sight and least obstructed path. If there are more then one NPC's blocking your path, you will have to move each in turn.

[Steam forums](https://steamcommunity.com/app/38410/discussions/0/619568794102678310/?insideModal=1)

> The shove command should be there for any NPC that is not set to stand at the exact same spot.

Comment: Brilliant!  This does the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

If giving the child a little shove isn't satisfying enough (see the other answer), there are *other* solutions.

If you don't want to get into trouble, you can still kill children (or any NPC) by using [Super Stimpaks](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Super_stimpak_(Fallout)) on them. NPC's love it when you use Stimpaks on them!

Super Stimpacks immediately heal for 75 health and then deal 9 damage over two minutes, *after* they've already done their healing.

Figure out how much health your target has (the [Awareness](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Awareness) perk can tell you exactly how much health they have), and apply enough Super Stimpaks to deal their health in damage over two minutes.

If they have 100 health (aka 'hp'), you'll need to use 12 Super Stimpaks on them to kill them (12 x 9hp = 108hp). Most children have around 25-30 health. Three Super Stimpaks would be enough for most kids (3 x 9hp = 27hp) and four should kill just about any of them (4 x 9hp = 36hp).

Simply apply enough Super Stimpacks to an NPC, wait, and watch them die as they take this gradual damage. [Nobody will suspect you're responsible](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Super_stimpak_(Fallout)#Use_for_assassination). Marvellous!

---

Ending this scenario in a non-discrete manner (eg. using a sledgehammer on the child's skull rather than administering Super Stimpaks to them) will earn you the [Childkiller](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Childkiller) perk. This perk reduces dialogue and reactions by 10% and random encounters on the travel map might now include bounty hunters who are out to get you. In general, you're just a terrible person.

On the other hand, you get the satisfaction of using a sledgehammer...